# How do I capture multiple invoices per order?

Tags: orders, sales, invoice

according to the documentation:

Multiple Invoices can be created per Order, containing as much or little of the purchased item quantity as you desire.

How do I do this? When I select ‘Invoice’ from a sales order, I have no options to change the quantities of items to invoice, and I can only invoice all of the items in the order.

Any help appreciated. We’re on EE 1.12.

Answer (score 3):

The input to change the qty appears only if the payment method used for the order can be captured partially or cannot be captured at all. See this method in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_Create_Items`

```
public function canEditQty()
{
    if ($this->getInvoice()->getOrder()->getPayment()->canCapture()) {
        return $this->getInvoice()->getOrder()->getPayment()->canCapturePartial();
    }
    return true;
}
```

The fact that the order can be captured is decided by these members in each payment model:

```
protected $_canCapture
protected $_canCapturePartial
```

or if the payment model overrides the methods `canCapture` and `canCapturePartial`

Comment: Thanks Marius - We're using Paypal Payflow Pro. Updating the $_canCapturePartial in the model allows me to set the products to be invoiced, but any subsequent requests to create an invoice on the order results in a  capture error. Thx

Comment: Well... probably there is a reason why you cannot partial capture a paypal payment.